# how to show Author information in search results

Tags: search, links, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, google-search, google-plus

Google search result does not show author information or thumbnail images.
the source code look like this

`<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/115911773396772351667/posts"/>`

procedure followed same like what google says. unfortunately the result doesn't appear.

here is the website link http://www.mohananvaidyar.org/

if anybody any body know the reason please answer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: That is what Google calls ["Rich Snippets"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) but it isn't really a WordPress specific question.

Comment: Did my solution help you out? Please an answer once it's solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Author Rich Snippets.

Your link needs to look like `<link href="https://plus.google.com/115911773396772351667?rel=author"/>Your Name</a>`

**The Simple Way To Set Up Author Rich Snippets**

There are a few things you need in order to step up Author Rich Snippets:

1. A public Google+ profile.
2. Make sure to upload a decent looking profile picture. Google will use this when it pulls in your Author Rich Snippet. If you already have a presence online, I recommend using the same photo you use elsewhere (Twitter, Facebook, Quora, etc).
3. Access to your blog

That, or a webmaster/IT guy who doesn’t hate your guts. You’ll need to tweak your blog posts or blog post template a bit.

Once you have these requisites taken care of, the first thing you’ll need to do is edit your Google+ profile. Head over to the “Contributor To” section: Click here to login and edit this section. What you want to do is add the site you write for (you can add as many as needed) so that Google knows that you are, as an author, associated with that website.
From there, you need to add a few things to your blog posts. What you need to do boils down to linking each of your blog posts with your profile on Google+ so that Google can clearly identify the relationship. We can do this using a link to your Google+ profile, coupled with the rel=author query string parameter.

1. Go to your Google+ profile and copy the URL
2. Insert a link in your blog post and use the copied URL as the destination (make sure to remove anything like /posts that’s at the end).
3. Make sure the anchor text is your full name (it should match the name used on your Google+ profile). `<link href="https://plus.google.com/115911773396772351667?rel=author"/>Your Name</a>`

Please look at http://www.swellpath.com/2012/04/author-rich-snippets-google/ for more info